# How to specify repeat until time in Timer object - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In the following timer:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Is there a way to specify end time for this `Timer` object?

In other words, what is the best way to gracefully end the timer after 20 minutes?

Comment: you want to end the timer whenever you want, or just make a timer that executes some code after 20 minutes? or maybe something else :D

Answer (score 1):

Add property `var seconds: Int = 0`
then in `updateTimer` function you can do next:

```
func updateTimer() {
     self.seconds += 5
     if self.seconds > 1200 {
         self.timer.invalidate()
         self.seconds = 0
     }
}
```

Comment: `Timer` isn't particularly accurate. It is better to take a `Date` when you start the timer and compare the current date against it, terminating if it is more than 20 minutes.